# Dropbox Datastore API Error on iOS: datastore default already open

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am using the following code in a few different view controllers to listen for Dropbox datastore changes.

Each view controller has a property defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DBDatastore *store;
```

And then I add an observer inside `listenForRemoteDataChanges` with this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  //Listen for remote Dropbox changes
  DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
  if(account){
    self.store = [DBDatastore openDefaultStoreForAccount:account error:nil];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [[PPDropboxSync sharedDropboxSync] listenForRemoteDataChanges:self.store weakController:weakSelf];
  }
}
```

...and then remove the observer with these methods:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  //Stop listening for Dropbox changes
  if(self.store) {
    [self.store removeObserver:self];
    [self.store close];
    self.store = nil;
  }
}
-(void)dealloc {
  //Deallocate NSNotifications (prevents mistakenly calling unavailable notification which causes crashes)
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

  //Stop listening for Dropbox changes
  if(self.store) {
    [self.store removeObserver:self];
    [self.store close];
    self.store = nil;
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error and the datastore sync subsequently fails:

> ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_ALREADYOPEN: database_manager.cpp:155: datastore default already open

It appears the `DBDatastore` stays open from controller to controller even though they each have their own `self.store` property. Why? I thought I was closing the datastore with the `viewWillDisappear` method using `[self.store close];` Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is probably called just before `viewDidDisappear`. You would be much better off putting all of the Dropbox code in some sort of "model" class that represents one datastore instance. Then each of your view controllers can share an instance of that model class. This will help ensure that only a single instance of any datastore exists in your app.

Comment: Hmm... okay. I've tried to centralize my Dropbox code in the `PPDropboxSync` class. Do you have an example of how I could share the datastore instance across classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clifton tried to explain, this means that you are opening it a second time (for the second view controller) before you close the first one. A datastore may only be opened once, until it is closed, so that is what the error is trying to tell you.

Perhaps you can use a singleton pattern?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I lost this one somehow. I went with a singleton and just open and close the same datastore across multiple view controllers in my app.